# Combine multiple layers of background with individual masks

Tags: css, mask

I have a background with several images and I want to give them dynamic color, so my plan was to stack multiple colors instead of the images and give each color a mask.
thats how I tried:

before:

```
background:
    url(/static/img/2x2black.svg) repeat-x top,
    url(/static/img/2x2black.svg) repeat-x bottom,
    var(--color-ground);
```

after:

```
background:
    var(--color-onground),
    var(--color-onground),
    var(--color-ground);
mask:
    url(/static/img/2x2black.svg) repeat-x top,
    url(/static/img/2x2black.svg) repeat-x bottom,
    none;
```

but that doesnt work.

Comment: explain the result your are trying to achieve. To start you cannot have different colors as backgroud like you are showing

Comment: I have at the moment several .svg images as background stack, and I want to implement a dark mode, so the color of the svgs should be set by a css-variable. so my plan was to stack the colors instead of the images and use the images as masks for each color. if theres an easier way to induce color into background images that would be great too

Comment: share an explicit example with your SVGs. It's difficult to imagine what you want to do without a concrete thing

Comment: ok updates my question

Comment: your question isn't that different from the previous one .. we still see nothing. We need a runnable code with real SVG, not placeholders. (Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) otherwise no one can help you